# Ansible vmware_host_facts with a loop

Tags: ansible, jinja

I'm trying to get a list of all of the datastores across multiple ESXi hosts (they all sit in different vCenters so I'm having to use a loop with a dictionary to get the correct vCenter for the ESXi host otherwise the hosts do not appear)

My problem is trying to comprehend the output. I've read the docs and I can't seem to figure a clear way to get the output I want. Consider the following from the docs as a working example - on one ESXi host.

```
- name: Gather vmware host facts from vCenter
  vmware_host_facts:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_server }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
    esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}"
  register: host_facts
  delegate_to: localhost
- debug:
    var: host_facts['ansible_facts']['ansible_datastore']
```

In my example, I add a loop to this to get the correct combination:

```
- name: Gather vmware host facts from vCenter
  vmware_host_facts:
    hostname: "{{ item.vcs }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
    esxi_hostname: "{{ item.host }}"
  register: host_facts
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop:
     - { host: 'mtboskt1bl07.oam.eeint.co.uk', vcs: 'vmtvcsakt01.oam.eeint.co.uk' }
     - { host: 'mtaoskt1bl10.oam.eeint.co.uk', vcs: 'vmtvcsakt01.oam.eeint.co.uk' }
```

The var 'host_facts' is a dictionary containing three entries: *msg*, *changed* and *result*.

If I access *result* - it is a list of dictionaries but I cannot seem to access any entries.

I've looked at the 'subelement' documentation but can't see how I'd apply it here. Anyone able to assist me further?

Comment: `but I cannot seem to access any entries.` - How are you trying to access it?  What happens if you just do a debug on the var `host_facts` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are referring to is `results` (plural with an `s`) as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)

> When you register a variable in a task with a loop, the registered variable contains a value for each item in the loop. The data structure placed in the variable during the loop will contain a `results` attribute, that is a list of all responses from the module. For a more in-depth example of how this works, see the [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#playbooks-loops) section on using register with a loop.

In your case, your loop contains two iterations. Taking your above var example, the equivalent with the loop for the first iteration would be:

```
- debug:
    var: host_facts.results[0].ansible_facts.ansible_datastore
```

If you want to get all datastores collected from the previous loop you can loop on the results:

```
- debug:
    var: item.ansible_facts.ansible_datastore
  loop: "{{ host_facts.results }}"
```